# Insert OOXML comment with track changes

Tags: ms-word, office-js

In my Word add-in I am inserting comments by replacing the selected text with OOXML that contains the comment.

With "Track Changes" turned on Word registers this as 3 actions: delete+insert+comment. It even inserts a paragraph break but I am unsure if that is related.

Is there a way to only have it register as a comment action like when inserting a comment using Word functionality?

Using [`rangeObject.insertOoxml`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range) I tried to insert at the beginning and at the end of the string without any luck since the two OOXML inserts does not seem to relate (which makes sense):

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
    var range = context.document.getSelection();

    var preBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage"><pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml" /></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="256"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/comments" Target="comments.xml" /></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"><pkg:xmlData><w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:body><w:p>';
    var postBody = '</w:p></w:body></w:document></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/comments.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.comments+xml"><pkg:xmlData><w:comments xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"><w:comment w:id="0" w:author="Some User" w:date="2016-10-26T10:11:05" w:initials="SU"><w:p><w:r><w:t>My comment</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:comment></w:comments></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part></pkg:package>';

    var before = preBody + '<w:commentRangeStart w:id="0" />' + postBody;

    var afterBody = '<w:commentRangeEnd w:id="0" /><w:r><w:commentReference w:id="0" /></w:r>';
    var after = preBody + afterBody + postBody;

    range.insertOoxml(before, Word.InsertLocation.start);
    range.insertOoxml(after, Word.InsertLocation.end);
    return context.sync().then(function () {
        console.log('OOXML added to the beginning and the end of the range.');
    });
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great question, thanks for asking it. When you use the insertOoxml method you are actually **writing** in the document's body, hence the behavior you observe when track changes is active, that's by design. There is no workaround for this, as of now. This issue will be solved when we support comments as a main feature of the API (and not inserting ooxml as  workaround). Make sure to add your request or vote for an existing on in our uservoice!  https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/163566-add-in-word

Btw there was a bug we fixed a few months ago that the insertOoxml method was inserting a extra paragraph, make sure to update your Word to get the latest bug fixes. If this is still happening please share your Office Version number.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Juan. I am really looking forward to that functionality as it will greatly improve a live add-in.

Comment: I noticed that there is `Property > comments` in [version 1.3](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/WordJs_1.3_Openspec) of the API. Is this where we can expect this functionality to be available?

There are already mulitple requests on uservoice e.g [first](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/15055839-wrapping-ooxml-apis-needed-insertcomment-insert) and [second](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13496982-create-word-comments-via-office-api).

Comment: I did indeed notice that the extra paragraph bug was fixed. This time it only applies when track changes is enabled.

(multiple comments due to character limit)

Comment: Great that you see it. We definitely consider the feedback of uservoice for future additions to the API. Btw the "comments" property that you are referring to is not precisely what you think. We'll soon add support for Custom and Built-in doc properties, the "comment" you see on the spec refers to a built in property, not to specific comments on the body of the document. (its usually used to set a comment on the overall content of the document.

Comment: That makes sens :)

Neither of the two uservoice requests have been commented by your team but _[Ability to manipulate Excel comments](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/10742331-ability-to-manipulate-excel-comments)_ has. Will you be shipping the built in comments for all applications at the same time? Do you have any idea of when this might be prioritized?

Comment: We reviewed the user voice requests today and will be updated very soon on the site . Most probably we will not do it at the same time. I do t have a specific timeline at this point .

Comment: This was a very helpful back and forth - thank you.

Is there any way to include a clickable link using insertOOXML? I can only get plain text to insert...

I've looked at the OOXML for a comment created manually that includes a link...it is very complex and the link is stored (as a reference) in comment.xml.rels.

Comment: this should be doable, just make sure to add a comment with a link, select it and get the OOXML with the API, then use that OOXML stream to modify whatever link you want to insert.