# Can you programmatically create HTML links in a OOXML-injected comment in MS Word?

Tags: xml, openxml, docx, office-js, office-addins

Updating question to be more specific...

I am able to insert a custom comment into a Word document using a couple of different strategies (see [Insert OOXML comment with track changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261291/insert-ooxml-comment-with-track-changes)) or the code below (which is passed a file location for comment.xml and a 'msg' or comment to be inserted).

But I cannot see how to include a clickable link in the OOXML.

I can get plain text links to appear, if they're part of 'msg'...but passing HTML breaks the XML and throws an error.

Links in Word comments are actually stored in comment.xml.rels and only referenced in the XML of the actual comment...so you'd perhaps have to append data to comment.xml.rels in order to programmatically create a link.

Anyone dealt with this and been able to include clickable links?

It's frustrating...once the plain-text comment appears that includes a link all you have to do is type a space after the link and it becomes clickable. I'm trying to avoid that manual (and ugly) step.

```
function insertComment2(fileName, msg) {

  var selectedText = "";
  var searchText = "";
  var replaceText = "";
  var myXML = "";

   Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(
 Office.CoercionType.Text,function (result) {
   if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
       console.log('Action failed. Error: ' + result.error.message);
   }
   else {
      selectedText = result.value;
      console.log('Selected data: ' + selectedText);
      var myOOXMLRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      myOOXMLRequest.open('GET', fileName, false);
      myOOXMLRequest.send();
      if (myOOXMLRequest.status === 200) {
          myXML = myOOXMLRequest.responseText;
          console.log("XML before insertion: " + myXML);
      }
      // selectedText = getDataFromSelection();
      var searchRangeTxt = "<w:r><w:t xml:space=\"preserve\">selectedText</w:t></w:r>"
      var replaceRangeTxt = "<w:r><w:t xml:space=\"preserve\">" + selectedText + "</w:t></w:r>"

      myXML = myXML.replace(searchRangeTxt, replaceRangeTxt);

      msg = "<![CDATA[" + msg + "]]>";

      var searchText = "<w:p><w:r><w:t>comment</w:t></w:r></w:p>";
      var replaceText = "<w:p><w:r><w:t>" + msg + "</w:t></w:r></w:p>";
      myXML = myXML.replace(searchText, replaceText);

      // var timeStamp = Date().toLocaleString();
      var currentdate = new Date();
      var timeStamp =    currentdate.getFullYear() + "-"
                      + ("0" + (currentdate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)  + "-"
                      + ("0" + currentdate.getDate()).slice(-2) + "T"
                      + currentdate.getHours() + ":"
                      + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
                      + currentdate.getSeconds() + "Z";

      console.log('Trying to get time and think it is: ' + timeStamp);

      var searchDate = "<w:comment w:id=\"0\" w:author=\"Proofreading International\" w:date=\"DATE\" w:initials=\"PRI\">";
      var replaceDate = "<w:comment w:id=\"0\" w:author=\"Proofreading International\" w:date=\"" + timeStamp + "\" w:initials=\"PRI\">";

      myXML = myXML.replace(searchDate, replaceDate);

      Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(myXML, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Ooxml }, function (asyncResult) {
               if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
                   console.log("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
                   console.log('Failure in inserting XML!' + myXML);
               }
               else {
                 console.log('success in inserting XML!' + myXML);
               }
           });
       }
  });
```

}

---

Updating...

Inserting the following 'comment.xml' file DOES create a hoverable hyperlink in the Comment...but it's an empty hyperlink and doesn't pick up the ID reference to the  section...

With a plain/empty Word doc, inserting a comment does NOT create a comments.xml.rels file. That file only gets created when you manually create a Comment with a link.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<pkg:package
    xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
    <pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512">
        <pkg:xmlData>
            <Relationships
                xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
                <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml"/>
            </Relationships>
        </pkg:xmlData>
    </pkg:part>
    <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/comments.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="256">
        <pkg:xmlData>
            <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
                <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink" Target="http://www.google.com/" TargetMode="External"/>
            </Relationships>
        </pkg:xmlData>
    </pkg:part>
    <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="256">
        <pkg:xmlData>
            <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
                <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/comments" Target="comments.xml"/>
            </Relationships>
        </pkg:xmlData>
    </pkg:part>
    <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
        <pkg:xmlData>
            <w:document
                xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
                <w:body>
                    <w:p>
                        <w:commentRangeStart w:id="0"/>
                        <w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">selectedText</w:t></w:r>
                        <w:r>
                            <w:commentReference w:id="0"/>
                        </w:r>
                        <w:commentRangeEnd w:id="0"/>
                    </w:p>
                </w:body>
            </w:document>
        </pkg:xmlData>
    </pkg:part>
    <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/comments.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.comments+xml">
        <pkg:xmlData>
            <w:comments xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
                <w:comment w:id="0" w:author="Proofreading International" w:date="DATE" w:initials="PRI">
                  <w:p>
                  <w:r>
                    <w:t>
                      New comment
                    </w:t>
                  </w:r>
                  <w:hyperlink Id="rId2" w:history="1">
                    <w:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                    <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:t>Google</w:t>
                    </w:r>
                  </w:hyperlink>
                </w:p>
                </w:comment>
            </w:comments>
        </pkg:xmlData>
    </pkg:part>
</pkg:package>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend you to do is the following:

1. Manually insert a comment with a link, just like you want it.
2. Select the range including the comment and then get the OOXML associated with it using the API. Here is an example on how to do it:

```js
var myOOXML="";
     function getOOXML() {
        Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync("ooxml", {}, function (result) {
            myOOXML = result.value;
            document.getElementById("txtTest").value = result.value
        })


     }
```

3. Grab that OOXML and try to minimize it using the [tips on this article](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml.md). Also look for the text and the url so you can replace it with what you need.
4. Finally, now that you know the text you need to replace, make sure to use a code similar to this one to insert the OOXML wherever you need it.

```js
  Word.run(function (ctx) {

             var myTempOOXML = document.getElementById("txtTest").value;
             //replaces the selected range with OOXML
             ctx.document.getSelection().insertOoxml(myTempOOXML, "replace");
             return ctx.sync();


         }).catch(function (e) { app.showNotification(e.message)})
```

Hope this sets you up in the right path...
thanks!
Juan.

Comment: I had to fill in a lot - my skills are meager.

But I got a link working...

2 main changes:

The comment.xml.rels package part has to occur BELOW the comment text...

And there were some additional style tags...like
                    <w:rStyle w:val="CommentReference"/>
                    </w:rPr><w:annotationRef/>

I've got some polish to do and straighten out the formatting...but I think I'm on my way.

Comment: happy to hear that! now you can deal with any OOXML  :)